# Is my plan to drain foundation wall water reasonable?

Tags: basement, waterproofing

I am in the process of building out my basement and see that I have water in the cinder block walls.  I have a plan but I don't know if it will work and that is why I am posting this in the hope that someone who knows may respond.

I want to first drain the water by drilling drain holes in the blocks about 4" above the floor.  I would then drill another small hole at or as close to floor level as possible to drain all the water out.  Then I would seal the bottom hole and pump in something like self leveling cement which would fill the cavity up to the upper drain hole thus preventing water from pooling below that level.

I would then install 1/2" pvc pipe in each drain hole and seal around the pipes.  Using a 45 degree fitting turning down and connecting to a 3/4" pvc pipe running the length of the wall just above the floor and sloped to a sump at the far end.

My purpose for using this method is that when my basement was built, the builder poured the slab and footing at the same time and then build the cinder block walls on top of the slab unlike what I see where a foundation base is poured. walls build on it and the floor poured inside the walls. My other purpose is that I can do this myself, otherwise, I would have to spend considerable money to have the basement floor dug up.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to install drains at every block cavity (every 8 inches). Is that your intent?

Comment: before you do any of that, figure out where all this water is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be looking at something simpler, like the baseboard waterproofing systems shown [here](http://www.oregonfoundationrepair.com/basement-waterproofing/french-drain/basement-drain.html) and [here](http://waterproof.com/squidgee-dry-system.html) (links for visual reference only).

Even if you designed something similar yourself it would be easier and more likely to result in success than trying to fill the wall and seal all those pipe penetrations.